# JSON API shows correct results but does not return them when requested by widget using $.getJSON and callback

Tags: php, json, api, callback, getjson

I have created a JSON API using PHP for a desktop widget app I am developing, which has has the structure:

```
{"a":"b"}
```

The client (in other words the widget) requests the API using $.getJSON and requests the URL

```
"http://mylink.php?callback=?"
```

but no results are returned (whereas *when I type the same URL directly in the browser, the results are there and correct*). I also tried to request another JSON API (not created by me) and it works fine, *it returns results*. **So I am almost sure that the problem is in the way I create my API.**

The code for creating the JSON API in the server's side is the following:

```
<?php
  ..............
  $results = array();
  $results['a'] = 'b';
  $encoded = json_encode($results);
  $encoded_callback = '?' . '(' . $encoded . ')';
  echo $encoded_callback;
  return $encoded_callback;
?>
```

The javascript code only contains

```
$getJSON(url, output, function(...){
      ......
});
```

up to now and works fine with another API. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong, either with the creation of the API from the server or with the URL request from the client. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: can you post you javascript code?

Comment: @ChetanAmeta in javascript I have only used the $.getJSON function until now, with a printing inside... The problem is in the PHP code which creates the API or in the way the widget requests the API, but I don't know how to fix it...